# Solving cpanel errors from tracker

Tags: php, cpanel

Hi i keep getting 3 errors that im having trouble solving or understanding with no help from my host, I have taken the step to move host due to bad service in general but would still like to know more about the errors if anyone can help. Im hoping a bigger better host will help but im aware all errors should be investigated if anyone can shed some light on these. These errors are taken from the cpanel error log and my website is a tracker.

1) File does not exist: /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-login.php
This is odd because i do not use wordpress, theres no wp plugings or any reference to wp in my code.

2) File does not exist: /home/xxxx/public_html/index.php
I get this on a few files, the index.php is there everything works, but the cpanel error log keeps bringing it up

3) Cannot allocate memory: [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx] couldn't create child process: /usr/sbin/suphp for /home/xxxx/public_html/announce.php
I have tried changing the memory limit in php.ini & the disk usage is well under my limit

Any guidance would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The first one is probably an indicator of the other two.

1)  This error is in your log because a hacker is poking around your site looking for common pages than can be a point of entry.  In this case, the hacker is probably looking to verify the existence of a wp-login.php file so that they can try some passwords on it.

2)  I would guess this is the same as above, but you actually have an index.html file not an index.php file.

Comment: The main page index is php I use mvc so everything goes through index.php, I have a procedural site and a new one I updated to mvc/pdo I get same errors on both,  I'm certain it's not the code itself

Comment: Have you looked at your Apache requests.log?

Comment: not as experienced server side would this be the request log xxx.99.5.xx - - [02/Jun/2020:18:24:26 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 301 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Comment: Yes.  Are there requests to index.php from the same IP address?